# Question filtering rules

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I would like to achieve the following:

1. Filtering by a minimal number of favorite tags

   I have favorite tags and ignore tags and I can choose whether all questions with a favorite tag are shown or only those without an ignored tag.

   If I don't add to the ignore tags all things I do not know anything about I still get lots of questions that I cannot answer. And if a question tagged with one of my favourite tags is also tagged with one of my ignored tags this will be ignored too, even if it could be interesting for me.

   I would prefer a behaviour like **Show me only questions with at least two tags from my favorites.** (Maybe combined with maximal one tag from my ignore list, but this would be optional.)
2. Is there a way only to show the questions, that are new since my last call?

How can I achieve this? If it is impossible, but other people also need it, it may become a feature request.

Comment: I think you can only get those results by writing your own query on the [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: why did you delete the examples?

Comment: @am2 how many readers do you think don't know what you mean by tags?

Comment: So, is this a [meta-tag:discussion], a [meta-tag:feature-request], or a request for [meta-tag:support]?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Isn't this obvious? The OP wants to discuss whether there is enough support for a feature request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I am sure, all Readers know the concept, but in my world an example, espechially if it mentioned in the description around, helps to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @Cerbrus: when I wrote the question I really didn't know whether I am too stupid (Support), nobody needs this (discussion) or it should be implemented (feature request)

Comment: I edited your question in order to make it a bit more clear (as I understood it from the question and your comments). I hope it's still in line with what you actually want to ask.

Comment: @Trilarion: Thank you, seems to clarify. But I cannot choose, only to show question with a favorite tag, there is no such Option, isn't it?

Comment: I think this question isn't unclear and wrongly closed. Voted for reopen. User am2 wishes to find questions that contain at least two of his favorite tags and at most 0 or 1 of his ignored tags (possibly limited to a data range) but doesn't know how to achieve this. I think this is clear enough.

Comment: @am2 I will try to come up with a custom query on the Data Explorer or you can experiment there too. See link in the first comment, the one by rene.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand why the question is closed. I still do not know, how to filter in a way that matches to me. The tip with the Data Explorer needs experienced knowledge in SQL (espacially how to filter at least 2 matching tags), not every user of this community will have this, even I do not know, how much time it will take me to solve the problem. I think, either someone can help me or the question should be reopened.

Comment: I'm on it but I have some problems with the Data Explorer currently. It may take a bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

The User Interface of the Stack Overflow website does not seem to offer the abilities you ask of it.

Using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer I created a custom query to achieve that [Questions with at least two of my favorite tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/565681/questions-with-at-least-two-of-my-favorite-tags) however you have to specify the two tags instead of taking just any two out of a set and there is also no possibility to read out the favorite tags of a user (it seems). Adding an ignored tag is straighforward, `charindex` should then return 0. There is an inbuilt date limit, which restricts the search to only the XX last days (give the number as negative number).

With Stack Exchange [custom filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters) you might be able to achieve the same or even more.

However, I doubt you can achieve exactly what you want given the tools. It does not seem possible to easily choose any two out of all your favorite tags and any one from your ignored tag. And also I doubt the whole search frameworks includes a notion of last call, which would be needed for your second point.

Sorry, I actually think your request is reasonable and the functions would be useful.

Comment: I do not understand your comment, sorry. In my mind it is not a false positive, if at least one or two tags match my knoledge.

Comment: @am2 CodeCaster is pointing out that a favorite tag python would also give matches for python-2.7. I don't think this is too bad since most questions tagged python-2.7 probably also could/should be tagged python. So the "quite" in "quite inpractical" is debatable. I use the query for myself and find it quite useful.

Comment: If I look for python and get python... too this would even be better.

Comment: @Trilarion yeah you're right. :) Removed that remark.